# What encryption is this? any idea?

Tags: url, encryption, encoding

Recently I stumbled upon a URL for one online mock test. The URL had the following after the domain name

/DescriptiveQuestions/**F66471F5-B15F-4B1A-8434-FC3D93D92C2D**

As you can see the ending part F66471F5-B15F-4B1A-8434-FC3D93D92C2D, I would like to know what kind of encoding is that. I searched for HEXADECIMAL but I dont think thats the one because when I decode it, I am getting just few symbols. I doubt thats base64 as well.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like encrypted data.

It looks like a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) ... a unique identifier.  That means that it has no content that can be decrypted.

(Version 3 & version 5 UUIDs are formed by hashing some data; e.g. a string.  But even in that case, it is theoretically impossible to recover the original data.  There is an infinite number of input strings that could hash to a given UUID.)

Answer (score 2):

F66471F5-B15F-4B1A-8434-FC3D93D92C2D is a GUID, (Global Unique Indentifier) also known as a UUID.

Given the url path `/DescriptiveQuestions/F66471F5-B15F-4B1A-8434-FC3D93D92C2D` It seems `F66471F5-B15F-4B1A-8434-FC3D93D92C2D` is the DescriptiveQuestion identifier.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)

> A globally unique identifier (GUID, /ˈɡwɪd/ or /ˈɡuːɪd/) is a unique
>   reference number used as an identifier in computer software. The term
>   "GUID" typically refers to various implementations of the universally
>   unique identifier (UUID) standard.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) GUIDs are usually stored as
>   128-bit values, and are commonly displayed as 32 hexadecimal digits
>   with groups separated by hyphens, such as:
>   21EC2020-3AEA-4069-A2DD-08002B30309D

Comment: @Rohith vsn. Yes, there is nothing to decrypt.